# Paperclip::Error in RecipesController#create

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have problem with **gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.1'** in Rails5. When I create an recipe with an image there's an error:

**Paperclip::Error in RecipesController#create**

**There was an error processing the thumbnail for 3c39a73424a219191afdb65e04f66d5d20160927-18689-1c0lj5f**

pointing to the controller create method.
I have *installed ImageMagic*

This is recipe controller:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_recipe, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def index
    @recipe = Recipe.all.order("created_at DESC")
end

def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
end

def show
end

def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
    if @recipe.save
        redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Succesfully created new recipe'
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
end

def update
    if @recipe.update(recipe_params)
        redirect_to @recipe
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @recipe.destroy
    redirect_to root_path, notice:"Succesfully deleted"
end

private

def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :description, :image)
end

def find_recipe
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
end
```

end

This is model:

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "400x400#>" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
```

end

and the _form.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for @recipe, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
    - if @recipe.errors.any?
        #errors
            %p
                = @recipe.errors.count
                Prevented this recipe froms saving
            %ul
                - @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                    %li= msg
    .panel-body
        = f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
        = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
        = f.input :image, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

    = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

and migration file for paperclip:

```
class AddAttachmentImageToRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :recipes do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
     remove_attachment :recipes, :image
  end
end
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: is there any error backtrace?

Comment: `image` in `recipe_params` is just a string (you have just `f.input :image`)?

Comment: try to change your image input to `f.input :image, as: :file, ...`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't work :/